# reduceByKey RDD spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have **RDD[(String, String, Int)]** and want to use reduceByKey to get the result as shown below. I don't want it to convert to DF and then perform groupBy operation to get result. **Int** is constant with value as 1 always.

Is it possible to use reduceByKey here to get the result? Presenting it in Tabularformat for easy reading

***Question***

| String | String | Int |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Apple | 1 |
| Second | Banana | 1 |
| First | Flower | 1 |
| Third | Tree | 1 |

***Result***

| String | String | Int |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Apple,Flower | 2 |
| Second | Banana | 1 |
| Third | Tree | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `reduceByKey` if you have a Tuple3, you could use `reduceByKey` though if you had `RDD[(String, String)]`.

Also, once you `groupBy`, you can then apply `reduceByKey`, but since keys would be unique, it makes no sense to call  `reduceByKey`, therefore we use `map` to map one on one values.

So, assume `df` is your main table, then this piece of code:

```
val rest = df.groupBy(x => x._1).map(x => {
  val key = x._1 // ex: First
  val groupedData = x._2 // ex: [(First, Apple, 1), (First, Flower, 1)]

  // ex: [(First, Apple, 1), (First, Flower, 1)] => [Apple, Flower] => Apple, Flower
  val concat = groupedData.map(d => d._2).mkString(",")
  // ex: [(First, Apple, 1), (First, Flower, 1)] => [1, 1] => 2
  val sum = groupedData.map(d => d._3).sum

  (key, concat, sum) // return a tuple3 again, same format
})
```

Returns this result:

```
(Second,Banana,1)
(First,Apple,Flower,2)
(Third,Tree,1)
```

**EDIT**

Implementing `reduceByKey` without sum, if your dataset looks like:

```
val data = List(
  ("First", "Apple"),
  ("Second", "Banana"),
  ("First", "Flower"),
  ("Third", "Tree")
)

val df: RDD[(String, String)] = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
```

Then, this:

```
df.reduceByKey((acc, next) => acc + "," + next)
```

Gives this:

```
(First,Apple,Flower)
(Second,Banana)
(Third,Tree)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, @vilalabinot. In this case, if I have only RDD[String, String] then how should I implement reduceByKey. counting I can do later on.

Comment: Edited the post, added another case, hope that works for you, good luck!